# Nvidia GPU error while using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, gpgpu

Tensorflow session creation fails on GPU node with the below error:

> 2018-06-19 07:01:08.400165: E
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:154] Internal: failed
>   initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal:
>   failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_ECC_UNCORRECTABLE

Below is the GPU info

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.30                 Driver Version: 390.30                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 0000752C:00:00.0 Off |                    2 |
| N/A   39C    P8    25W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Please share some pointers to debug this further.

PS: Same program runs fine on CPU node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11839929/5330223) other `Stackoverflow` discussion,

I think your GPU state has corrupted bits and ECC or error correcting code couldn't correct it.

According to the discussion **restarting the computer** may help.

Another thing is that in your GPU info you see `Uncorr. ECC` which should be **N/A** but in your case, it's showing **2**. So my suggestion is that you restart the computer and confirm this `Uncorr. ECC` as `N/A` before running your program. So that you can ensure that your program is not engendering this issue.